# Integration Salesforce with Docusign Invalid type: dfsle.Envelope

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate the Salesforce with DocuSign with Docusign Apex Toolkit, but dfsle class is not available in my org. I installed the Apex Tool Kit (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/apex-toolkit-install/)

```
Id MySourceId = '00Q0m00000884XXXXX';

dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));

Lead myContact = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM lead where id = '00Q0m00000884XXXX'];

//use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
            myContact.Name, // Recipient name
            myContact.Email, // Recipient email
            null, //Optional phone number
            'Signer 1', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
            new dfsle.Entity(myContact.Id)); //source object for the Recipient


dfsle.UUID myTemplateId = dfsle.UUID.parse('28386dbc-2576-4637-bb77-c86938fe080f');

//create a new document for the Envelope
dfsle.Document myDocument = dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(
    myTemplateId, // templateId in dfsle.UUID format
    'Self Sales Teste'); // name of the template

// Send the envelope.
myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
    myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
    true); // Send now?


try {
    dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(envelope, true);
} catch (dfsle.APIException ex) {
    if (ex.error.code == dfsle.APIErrorCode.CONSENT_REQUIRED) {
        // user is a valid member of the DocuSign account, but has not granted consent to this application 
    } else {
        // handle other errors
    }
}
```

```
Error: Line: 3, Column: 1
Error: Invalid type: dfsle.Envelope
```

Comment: Can you go into your apex classes and check if the envelope class is there? If its not there was likely something wrong with the installation process.

Comment: Hi, this class is hidden. I follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue few weeks ago :) Go to your Salesforce Setup. Type Installed Packages in quick find box. Make sure the DocuSign App Launcher is installed. Check package prefix.

Comment: Is the DocuSign App Launcher same the DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce?

Comment: I think so. But with Apex Toolkit on board :)

Comment: Thank you Amurnabis